# Browsersync + Symfony2 login redirects not working

Tags: firefox, sass, gulp, browser-sync

I'm using [GulpJS](http://gulpjs.com/) with [BrowserSync](http://www.browsersync.io/) on a [Symfony 2](http://symfony.com/) site, to compile the projects's SCSS files. BrowserSync injects changed CSS into the browsers connected to localhost:3000 and this works really well.

The setup works well for Safari, iOS Simulator, Chrome, Opera and even Internet Explorer running through a virtual machine, however, Firefox is proving to have some issue with redirects.

In Firefox, when I hit **/login**, Symfony redirects to **/login_check** but instead of a successful login, the page simply redirects to **/login** as if nothing happened. No session is created and there is no way to get past the login screen in Firefox.

Looking at the body of /login_check, the following code snippet can be found, and I'm suspecting that this could be something to do with the problem:

```
<script type='text/javascript' id="__bs_script__">//<![CDATA[
    document.write("<script async src='/browser-sync/browser-sync-client.1.7.2.js'><\/script>".replace(/HOST/g, location.hostname).replace(/PORT/g, location.port));
//]]></script>
```

Debugging with Charles Proxy, the /login_check page shows:

**302 - Client closed connection before receiving entire response** Could it be that BrowserSync is redirecting too early?

I have looked around to try and find a solution for this, but couldn't find any resolution so far.

I've created a Gist with my [gulpfile.js](https://gist.github.com/josefvanniekerk/dc7fb5cdf617b343d142)...

Has anyone else had this problem before, and perhaps come up with a workaround?

Comment: I've now updated to v1.8.0 as per BS's instructions, but still no login in FF. After hacking the login, noticed that some URLs don't navigate, for example entering /products/list in the address bar, and some JS simply reverts it back to the current page and reloads.

Comment: Im having the exact same problem, did find a solution?